# New windows appear in top left corner of screen underneath Unity Launcher & top bar of deskop on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Tags: 16.04, unity, launcher

I've a strange problem on one of my machines in one user's profile: all newly opened windows open in the top left corner of the screen and are located underneath the Unity Launcher. It's not possible to grab their window bar, because it is underneath the desktop's top bar. It's not possible to close the windows, because the controls (X - ■) are underneath the Launcher. Each time, I've to hold ALT to be able to grab and move the window to a different location on the desktop.

What could be the cause?

How can I fix it?

Many thanks for help!